# Sql Sum OF related Tables

Tags: sql, sum

This Is SQL Statment:

```
SELECT
  dbo.tblWorkflow.WorkflowName,
  ISNULL((SELECT SUM(dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.ExecutedQuantity * dbo.tblOperationItemPrice.UnitPrice) AS Amount
          FROM dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution 
          INNER JOIN dbo.tblOperationItemPrice ON dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.OperationID = dbo.tblOperationItemPrice.OperationID
          GROUP BY dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaYear, 
                   dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaNO
          HAVING (dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaNO = dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.SchemaNO) AND 
                (dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaYear = dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.SchemaYear)), 0) AS ActualAmount

FROM dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblWorkflow ON dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.WorkflowID = dbo.tblWorkflow.WorkflowID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblWorkflowActivity ON dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.WorkflowActivityID = dbo.tblWorkflowActivity.WorkflowActivityID

WHERE (dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.StartDate IS NOT NULL) 
  AND (dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.FinishDate IS NULL) 
  AND (dbo.tblWorkflowActivity.ActivityName <> 'Execution')
```

and the output is:

```
WorkFlowName  :   ActualAmount
------------  :    ------------
Sceco         :      28020.00
Sevareg       :       5005.00
Sevareg       :       1100.00
```

How can I use sum to get total of Sevareg? like this

```
WorkFlowName  :   ActualAmount
------------  :    ------------
Sceco         :      28020.00
Sevareg       :       6105.00
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, using `GROUP BY` and `SUM`?

```
SELECT WorkflowName, SUM(ActualAmount)
FROM (SELECT dbo.tblWorkflow.WorkflowName,
             ISNULL ((SELECT SUM(dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.ExecutedQuantity * dbo.tblOperationItemPrice.UnitPrice) AS Amount 
                      FROM dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution 
                      INNER JOIN dbo.tblOperationItemPrice
                              ON dbo.tblOperationItemPrice.OperationID = dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.OperationID
                      GROUP BY dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaYear,
                               dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaNO 
                      HAVING (dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaNO = dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.SchemaNO) 
                         AND (dbo.tblSchemaOperation_Execution.SchemaYear = dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.SchemaYear)), 
                     0) AS ActualAmount

      FROM dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce 
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblWorkflow 
              ON dbo.tblWorkflow.WorkflowID = dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.WorkflowID
      INNER JOIN dbo.tblWorkflowActivity
              ON dbo.tblWorkflowActivity.WorkflowActivityID = dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.WorkflowActivityID
      WHERE (dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.StartDate IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (dbo.tblWorkflowActivtyInsatnce.FinishDate IS NULL) 
        AND (dbo.tblWorkflowActivity.ActivityName <> 'Execution')
     ) AS x
GROUP BY dbo.tblWorkflow.WorkflowName
```

Comment: it said: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or subquery.

Comment: this seems to be a problem with ms sql server, so you have to wrap it in another subselect. i updated the answer.